# Convex sets.Proof that sum of non-negative numbers multiplied by elements of convex set is in that convex set.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let's assume that $S$ is convex set in $X$ and ${\{\alpha_i}\}^n_{i=1}$ set of non-negative numbers such that $\sum_{i=0}^n {\{ \alpha_i} \} =1$.
Prove that $$\sum_{i=0}^n {\alpha_iu_i} \in S$$ where $u$ $$ \forall {\{ u_i }\} ^n_{i=1}\subset S$$

Comment: Any initial thoughts on where to go with this?

Comment: @TheoBendit I tried working with it as with the set of points that the simplex is determined by. But at this point, I'm just stuck.

Comment: Have you tried setting it up an induction argument? Remember, you can assume $\alpha_i > 0$ for all $i$, as you can always discard the $0$ terms.

Comment: @TheoBendit nope, and I'm not quite sure how to do that, can you please show how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We proceed by induction on $n$. For $n = 1$, our sum contains one element, and our one coefficient is $1$. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u_i = u_1 \in S$, which proves the $n = 1$ case.

Suppose every convex combination of $n$ elements of $S$ produces an element of $S$, and consider a convex combination of $n + 1$ elements:
\begin{align}&\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_i u_i &\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i = 1, \alpha_i \ge 0.\end{align}
If $\alpha_{n+1} = 0$ for any $i$, then we may omit the term from the sum, giving us a convex combination of $n$ terms:
\begin{align}&\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i u_i &\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i = 1, \alpha_i \ge 0,\end{align}
which is in $S$ by the hypothesis. Otherwise, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1 - \alpha_{n+1} < 1$, and we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_i u_i &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i u_i + \alpha_{n+1} u_{n+1} \\
&= (1 - \alpha_{n+1})\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\alpha_i}{1 - \alpha_{n+1}} u_i\right) + \alpha_{n+1} u_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
Let $b_i = \frac{\alpha_i}{1 - \alpha_{n+1}}$. Then note that $b_i \ge 0$ for all $i$, and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i}{1 - \alpha_{n+1}} = 1$$. Thus,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\alpha_i}{1 - \alpha_{n+1}} u_i$$
is a convex combination of $n$ vectors from $S$, and hence lies in $S$. This therefore means that
$$(1 - \alpha_{n+1})\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\alpha_i}{1 - \alpha_{n+1}} u_i\right) + \alpha_{n+1} u_{n+1}$$
is a convex combination of two vectors from $S$ (as in the definition of convexity), and hence lies in $S$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Now it's all clear, amazing explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $n=2$ this is just the definition of convexity since

$$a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 = a_1u_1 + (1-a_1)u_2 \in S$$

Assume it holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$, then $a_{n+1} = 1$ so $a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_nu_n + a_{n+1}u_{n+1} = u_{n+1} \in S$.

Otherwise, note that:

$$a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_nu_n + a_{n+1}u_{n+1} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)\left(\frac{a_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}u_1 + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}u_n\right) + a_{n+1}u_{n+1}$$

Now $$y = \frac{a_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}u_1 + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}u_n \in S$$

by the inductive assumption, and then  $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)y + a_{n+1}u_{n+1} \in S$ by the base case.

Comment: Well no: $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}u_1 + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}u_n\right)$ is equal to $u_1+\dots u_n$, not what you say it equals.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** for the induction step: If $\alpha_{n+1}=1$ you're done; assume $t=\alpha_{n+1}<1$. Then $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\alpha_ju_j=(1-t)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\alpha_j}{1-t}u_j\right)+tu_{n+1}.$$Now verify that $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\alpha_j}{1-t}$ equals *what* and you're done.

Comment: I believe my answer offers the same approach.

Comment: @mechanodroid ??? Unless I haven't seen the edit yet, your answer is _wrong_. You've acknowledged it was wrong, thanking  me for the correction, so I really can't see your point.

Comment: I have edited it. Isn't $$\frac{\alpha_j}{1-\alpha_{n+1}} = \frac{\alpha_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i}$$?

Comment: @mechanodroid Yes. So now there are three answers, giving the same solution in varying degrees of detail. That's the way things work when there's basically one obvious answer...